# Adding Custom HTML/CSS/JS code in specific page

Tags: customization, javascript, html

I've written a HTML/JS code, it's something like a survey which consists of code like this:

```
 <div class="Question">
        <h3>1. I have the knowledge of procedures needed for starting and running a business <span class="star">
                *</span></h3>

        <br>

        <div class=None>
            <input type="radio" name="Q1" id="none1" value="None">
            <label for="none1">None</label>
        </div>

        <div class=Withguidance>
            <input type="radio" name="Q1" id="wguid1" value="With Guidance">
            <label for="wguid1">With Guidance</label>
        </div>

        <div class=Beginner>
            <input type="radio" name="Q1" id="beg1" value="Beginner">
            <label for="beg1">Beginner</label>
        </div>

        <div class="Intermediate">
            <input type="radio" name="Q1" id="inter1" value="Intermediate">
            <label for="inter1">Intermediate</label>
        </div>

        <div class="Expert">
            <input type="radio" name="Q1" id="ex1" value="Expert">
            <label for="ex1">Expert</label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

At the end of the questions, there is a button that uses jsPDF library to convert the answers inputted by the user into a custom PDF that i made. Now this works perfectly when running the raw html file. The problem comes when i tried to insert it on my Wordpress site. 
Firstly, i use the latest version of Wordpress and Elementor (Wordpress 5.7.1 and Elementor Pro 3.1.1)

 
At the trial phases , before my code was complete, i could add it perefectly fine using the HTML widget on Elementor. As the code got bigger and lines were added, Elementor started lagging everytime i copied pasted my code. When my code was finished, when i tried to copy paste my code in Elementor, the page tab got unresponsive and couldn't do anything than close the tab. I couldn't paste my code in the HTML widget regardless how many times i tried. 
I then tried using the Gunberg editor, while the code pasted and the tab was responsive, when i tried to update, there was an error "Update failed". 
Is there anyway that i can paste the code to my page without it crashing? Maybe with a plugin or via source files?  
I already tried WP Coder but it didnt work.

P.S. I use 2 base64 strings, one for an image and one for a font that may be the reason that the editors cant handle the code. The base64 strings worked perefectly fine at the beginning,  before the code got bigger.

Thanks in advance!
(sorry if my English is poor, not a native speaker)

Answer (score 1):

If this is relatively static code treat it as such and put it in a file or template.

There are a couple of easy ways of doing this.

**Via templates**

[Look at the way that WP does it](https://themes.svn.wordpress.org/twentytwenty/1.7/) - you have a folder called `template-parts` - insert your code there and call it in a template type. Assign that page to that template type.

**Via a file**

Above you mention this is for a single page. Look in your theme for `page.php` or `singular.php` `single.php` take that and create a template for that page yourself. You can [create a file that will define](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#single-page) that page by calling it `page-{slug}.php` or `page-{id}.php`.

A super basic version of this could be

```
<?php
get_header(); ?>

<main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

    <?php
        // Start the Loop.
        while ( have_posts() ) :
            the_post();

            // This will add your content you enter in the wp-admin side
            the_content();
            endwhile; // End the loop.
        ?>
        <div class="Question">
            <h3>1. I have the knowledge of procedures needed for starting and running a business <span class="star">
                    *</span></h3>
        ...................... 
        ETC

</main><!-- #main -->
<?php
get_footer();
```